# Changing order of iterated integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I am given an integral $\int_0^2\int_0^{4-y^2}\int_0^{y/2} f(x,y,z) dxdzdy$. Hence, retrieving the respective inequalities:

$0<=x<=y/2$

$0<=z<=4-y^2$

$0<=y<=2$

I have tried interchanging the order to $dydzdx$ and this is what I derived at:

$\int_0^1\int_0^{4-4x^2}\int_0^{2x} f(x,y,z) dydzdx$, however my answer is incomplete, may I know what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are given $x \leq y/2$, i.e., $2x \leq y$. Therefore your innermost integral should not go from $0$ to $2x$ but rather from $2x$ to $2$.